# After login successfully, URL not changing in yii2-app-basic

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii2-basic-app

I was going to About Page after Successfully login. It's OK.

But, URL not changing to About Page. It is same as login Page, but the content of page is About Page.

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) 
    {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        return $this->render('about'); // Here
    }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

URL is same as `http://localhost/myProject/yii/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin`.
It should be `http://localhost/mylawsuit/yii/web/index.php?r=site%2Fabout`

So, how to change URL after login.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of rendering `about` view, you should simply use a redirection :

```
return $this->redirect(['about']);
```

Answer (score 1):

your answer:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{
     $this->redirect(['about']); // change here to this
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr Mohsen, I can't do that. Because Mr @Soju Answered First. But, I Up voted Your Answer. Thanks For Answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Yii::$app->request->referrer`  here a Yii [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$referrer-detail%22documentation%22)

Answer (score 1):

You are `rendering` the `about view` in `actionLogin`. obviously your `URL` will be login & have content of `about view`.

Try something like this.

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) 
    {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        return $this->redirect('about'); // Change it to redirect
    }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
public function actionAbout()
{
   return $this->render('about');
}
```

Hope it will help!